# Searching a named vector in r

Tags: r

In a named vector i want those words starting with good along with their frequency. I am getting the word only but not frequency

```
v <- c(10,20,30,40,50)
names(v) <- c("good afternoon", "hi", "this","good morning","what")
v
# gives error
grep("^good",v,value = TRUE)

# below code works but frequency not showing
grep("^good",names(v),value = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking.

You could `stack` the vector to give a `data.frame` with two columns: the `values` corresponding to your frequency (?) and the expression `ind`.

```
stack(v)
#  values            ind
#1     10 good afternoon
#2     20             hi
#3     30           this
#4     40   good morning
#5     50           what
```

Then to get the frequency and expression that matches your regexp you could do

```
stack(v)[grep("^good", stack(v)$ind), ]
#  values            ind
#1     10 good afternoon
#4     40   good morning
```

---

In response to your comment, is this what you're after?

```
v[grep("^good", names(v))]
#good afternoon   good morning
#            10             40
```

This return object is again a named vector with the vector entries giving the frequencies and the names of the vector corresponding to the expressions.

Comment: @ Maurits Evers can't named vector be searched directly without transforming it to data frame. basically i just want a subset of named vector with its frequency intact

Answer (score 0):

You want number of hits?

```
length(grep("^good",names(v)))
# [1] 2
```